# delay jQuery mouseleave or toggleClass

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a pretty simple hover menu, and I'm trying to figure out how to deal with timing.

The goal is to delay the `mouseleave` event by 500, and/or not react to quick passes over other menu items.

The basic function:

```
$('.button').on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $(this).children('.menu').addClass('open');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).children('.menu').removeClass('open');
  }, 
});
```

The main problem with this is the pixel gap between the button and menu - when a user moves the mouse towards the menu then that triggers the `mouseleave` function.

A second annoyance is when passing the mouse quickly over sibling buttons they also trigger their `mouseenter` functions.

I have also tried but no reaction...

```
mouseleave: function() {

  setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).children('.menu').removeClass('open');
  }, 500);},

});
```

and I have also tried using

```
.delay(500).queue(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("open").dequeue();
```

but it seems unsteady to me.

`console.log($.ui.version)` prints `1.11.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider waiting the 500ms, then checking if the condition you are looking at (hovered vs. not) is still true.

If so, *then* take the appropriate action.

```js
$('.button').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    waitEnterExit(this, true);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    waitEnterExit(this, false);
  },
});


function waitEnterExit(el, inside) {
  var button = $(el);

  setTimeout(function() {
    var hovered = button.is(':hover');

    if (hovered && inside)
      button.children('.menu').addClass('open');
    else if (!hovered && !inside)
      button.children('.menu').removeClass('open');
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=button>1
  <p class=menu>inner</p>
</div>
<div class=button>2
  <p class=menu>inner</p>
</div>
<div class=button>3
  <p class=menu>inner</p>
</div>
<div class=button>4
  <p class=menu>inner</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Paul Roub, perfect solution and presentation!

Answer (score 1):

The response above is correct, but I just want to make a note (cannot comment, because of low reputation, so I'm leaving it as an answer).

Note that, the mouseleave you used won't work to remove the classes in this case.

```
mouseleave: function() {
  //Won't remove .open
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).children('.menu').removeClass('open');
  }, 500);},
});
```

What happens is that, the $(this) in the setTimeout function is the Window, not your button. If you want to target your button, you would have to pass it for the setTimeout function. One way of doing it is by creating a variable with *this*. You can test it by calling console.log with $(this) inside and outside the setTimeout function to see what gets printed in the console.

```
mouseleave: function() {
  // caller now is the equivalent to this
  var caller = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    // $(this) equivalent to the .button in this case
    $(caller).children('.menu').removeClass('open');
  }, 500);},
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for adding this!